# Views not registered in django rest urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

Why my views is not registered in url?

here's my view code,

```
class AView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response(apps.get_models())
```

here's my url code

```
from a_module import views
from .views import *
from rest_framework_nested import routers

app_name = 'a_module'

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'endpoint', views.AView, base_name="endpoint")

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

There's other view in a_module that registered in url, but the only view that is not registered is AView, i tried registering with views.AView.as_view() it doesn't work too. It when I access the view through `/endpoint` it returns not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your view class does not inherited from **`Viewsets`**, you can not use a **`router`** here.
 So, remove those portions and directly mention the view class in **`urls()`** function with **`.as_view()`** as below,

```
from a_module import views
from .views import *
app_name = 'a_module'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'endpoint/', views.AView.as_view(),name='endpoint'),
]
```

Comment: should say: "Since your view class does not inherited from Viewsets, you can not use a router" ;)

Comment: @Linovia that's nice